# Как получить id элемента JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlet

Есть плитка(ul li). Каждый блок плитки размерами 200px X 100px. Каждая плитка это ссылка. Ссылка ведёт на другой сайт.Эти ссылки достаются из БД и формируются в JSP файле. Теперь предстала задача сделать удаление этих ссылок(крестик на плитке). 
Суть в том что мне нужно передать id ссылки в бд. Его я получаю, когда вытаскиваю из БД всё в ArrayList-е.
Сам li строится таким образом:

```
List<Link> links = (ArrayList<Link>) request.getAttribute("links");
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    Link link = links.get(i);
%>
<li id="<%=link.Id %>" class="link"><a class="aDescription"  href="ViewDescription"></a><a class="aDeleteLink" href="RemoveLink"></a>
<a class="aTitle" href="<%=link.link.toString()%>" target="_blank"><p><%=link.title.toString()%></p></a></li>
<%
}
%>
```

Я li-ю присвоил id. Это id этой ссылки из БД.

Теперь вопрос. Как мне можно вытащить этот id?

Как вариант можно сделать . Сделать ему *display: none*. задать name и как value ставить id. Но тут опять же проблема - таких input-ов с одинаковыми именами может бть сколько угодно. как понять это именно то что нужно. поместить это всё в ?

Есть ещё какие-либо варианты как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Например так `<a class="aDescription"  href="ViewDescription?link_id=<%=link.Id %>"></a>` получается url с параметром запроса `link_id`: `ViewDescription?link_id=123`. Этот параметр извлекается при обработке запроса. его значением будет id вашего линка

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.
для начала за одним ключом в запросе может хранится массив значений которые извлекаются методом ServletRequest[.getParameterValues(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String))
Т.е благополучно отправляйте запрос на сервер с ключом "кудалению" получайте массив id и удаляйте их все скопом.
Можно поступить изящнее на стороне клиента организовать скрипт для работы с сервлетом ответственным за удаление.По каждому клику отправлять запрос GET  с id на сервер опять же незаметно для клиента

Comment: В данном случае удаляется только одна ссылка, соответственно мне нужен только один id.
Так же существует такая проблема. Если юзер закроет вкладку и зайдет на сайт его перебросит на home но тех данных не будет ибо они теряются когда вкладка закрывается. Соответственно нужно что-то более гибкое. перед этим я столкнулся с проблемой что если юзер закрывает вкладку и заходит заново то тот массив со ссылками получается NULL. Сделал костыль. 

Вопрос. Как на стороне клиента сделать скрипт?

Comment: Для начала с простыми вещами разберитесь, потом уже за скрипты. Не понятно как ваши юзеры перемещаются по страницам, но в любом случае следует запретить кеширование динамических страниц. Возможно в JSP есть какие-то инструкции для этого, которые помещаются на страницу. Далее идут более сложные способы.

Comment: Кажется именно вам я уже писал о фильтрах и слушателях? Судя по всему ваша логика построена не на добавлении данных к запросу на подлете к сервлету.jsp(добавление происходит в фильтре) а отдельной сущности посещение которой и наполняет ваш список?** В данном вопросе скрыт ответ как избежать NULL в массиве**

Comment: @Sergey Через сервлеты переходят. Тобишь jsp отсылает запрос на сервлет и уже сервлет перенаправляет на другую jsp.

У меня говно код. я знаю.

Comment: @PeterSlusar я не знаю ещё фильтров. В том и дело. Я ещё учусь, и прохожу всё постепенно. Я смотрел что такое фильтра, даже попробовал себе сделать. Мне это показалось весьма удобным, но не понял...как что и куда... Поэтому делаю так как знаю...

Идёт запрос на сервлет, тот обращается к классу который работает с БД и потом сервлет перекидывает на страницу. или обновляет текущую.

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов На самом деле так и рекомендуется поступать. Сервлет обрабатывает запрос и jsp рисует ответ, опираясь на данные полученные в сервлете. Что качается кеша, то его запретить не сложно. Всего добавить пару-тройку заголовков в ответ, где вам удобнее: в jsp или в сервлете или в фильтре. И это легко найти в гугле.

Comment: @Sergey кеш сейчас меня особо не волнует. Да я и не замечал что происходит кеширование. 

Меня больше беспокоит тот вопрос где хранить данные после ухода юзера со страницы после авторизации...

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов для этого есть сессия. Получают её вызвав метод  `request.getSession()`. У сессии  есть методы `getAttribute(java.lang.String name)` и `setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value)` специально предусмотренные для хранения и извлечения данных на протяжении этой сессии

Comment: @Sergey Благодарю!

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов в дополнение ответа Sergey Сеанс (session) - это последовательность запросов, отправляемых конкретным клиентом серверу, и ответов, полученных от Web-сервера... Я рекомендую базу знаний [ibm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp09238/)